# Enlarge grid coordinates?

Tags: javascript, math

I've a list of coordinates that define a grid of elements with different sizes.
Each element is positioned starting from the top left corner, giving the starting column, the starting row and its width and height.

```
{
  "col": 1,
  "row": 1,
  "size_x": 3,
  "size_y": 2
},
{
  "col": 4,
  "row": 1,
  "size_x": 3,
  "size_y": 2
},
{
  "col": 1,
  "row": 3,
  "size_x": 3,
  "size_y": 2
},

{
  "col": 4,
  "row": 3,
  "size_x": 3,
  "size_y": 2
},
{
  "col": 1,
  "row": 5,
  "size_x": 3,
  "size_y": 2
},
{
  "col": 4,
  "row": 5,
  "size_x": 3,
  "size_y": 2
}
```

This set of coordinates was defined on a 6 columns grid.

Now the grid has 12 columns (and each row is the half of before) so I need to multiply by 2 the `size_x` and `size_y`.

But this is not enough, I need also to update the `col` and `row` coordinates to prevent collisions and achieve the same layout of the old 6 columns grid.

This is the script I've prepared, it enlarges the `size_x` and `size_y` by 2, and fixes the `col` somehow... 
But I can't find a way to complete it and make it reliable.
http://codepen.io/FezVrasta/pen/qbrYGv?editors=001

The layout, once applied to the UI, should look like this:

```
[---][---]
[---][---]
[---][---]

- = 1 col
[ = 2 rows
```

Comment: these days people gives downvotes without any reason... meh

Comment: not my downvote, but 1.  no clearly defined problem statement, 2. no included code.  Actually, I think I will...

Comment: @Alnitak Even though the code is not included directly, there is a link to it (I prefer code here too, but I do not punish people for including their code elsewhere). The defined problem is he wants to resize the grid correctly every time. I do not see why the downvotes either. The question isn't perfect but people are pretty harsh here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% clear on the question, but I assume you want a six-column grid to evolve to a 12-column grid, and with some basic Math that is quite easy. I have renamed some variables to what I find comfortable to work with when talking about positioning, but the following logs the grid when it was 12 columns wide, and it will work with any grid you pass it that is structured as an array of objects (which hopefully only contain numbers).

**Update** I have corrected some stupid mistakes in my script and changed the output and input so you can see them directly in the snippet. Hope it helps!

```js
var grid = [
  { x: 1, y: 1, w: 3, h: 2 },
  { x: 4, y: 1, w: 3, h: 2 },
  { x: 1, y: 3, w: 3, h: 2 },
  { x: 4, y: 3, w: 3, h: 2 },
  { x: 1, y: 5, w: 3, h: 2 },
  { x: 4, y: 5, w: 3, h: 2 }
];


document.getElementById('input').textContent = JSON.stringify(grid);

function resizeGrid(grid, from, to){
  // Loop through the grid
  for(var i = 0; i < grid.length; i++)
     // Loop through the values of the grid
     for(var key in grid[i]) 
       // This is a safety check to not enumerate inherited properties
       // not necessary, but I find it safer when doing for..in loops
       if(grid[i].hasOwnProperty(key))
         // Simply divide the value by the original and 
         // multiply by the desired output
         grid[i][key] = grid[i][key] / from * to
  return grid;
}

document.getElementById('output').textContent = JSON.stringify(resizeGrid(grid, 6, 12));
```

```html
<div id="input"></div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

I am also not 100% sure how you set up your grid, but it might be best to keep your top-left most coordinate as `0` - the reason being that if you have something at `0, 0` it will remain in that corner when you resize the grid - if your coordinates start at `1`, this becomes much more complicated as `1,1` will now become `2,2`, even though it should not change. Always count from `0`!

In order to fix this `1,1`  problem, you can simply replace this line:

```
grid[i][key] = grid[i][key] / from * to;
```

with this line:

```
grid[i][key] = grid[i][key] === 1
    ? 1
    : grid[i][key] / from * to;
```

Heres an implementation:

```js
var grid = [
  { x: 1, y: 1, w: 3, h: 2 },
  { x: 4, y: 1, w: 3, h: 2 }
];


document.getElementById('input').textContent = JSON.stringify(grid);

function resizeGrid(grid, from, to){
  // Loop through the grid
  for(var i = 0; i < grid.length; i++)
     for(var key in grid[i]) 
       if(grid[i].hasOwnProperty(key))
         switch(key){
           case 'w': case 'h': grid[i][key] = grid[i][key] / from * to; break;
           case 'x': case 'y': grid[i][key] = (grid[i][key] - 1) / from * to + 1; break;
         }
  return grid;
}

document.getElementById('output').textContent = JSON.stringify(resizeGrid(grid, 6, 12));
```

```html
<div id="input"></div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: thanks but it doesn't seem correct. the x and y of the first object should not change as far I know. They should still be on the top left of the grid.

Comment: @FezVrasta I have just added a comment about that as it seems to me that you start counting from `1`, which you should not do. The top left of your grid should always be `0,0` as it _does not move_. If you want a quick fix that will work for you, you might simply want to reduce the value by 1 before you do a calculation and add it back at the end.

Comment: unlikely I can't change this, the script I give the data needs this format :( I'll try your suggestion and if it works I'll mark as correct. thanks!

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but then the size_y and size_x will not double, but 3 will become 5 (instead of 6)... Any idea? http://codepen.io/FezVrasta/pen/PZpaqz?editors=001

Comment: @FezVrasta I have added another snippet to correct for this behaviour, simply not multiplying 1 will do the trick. However, just for future reference, grids always start at coordinate `0,0` and this kind of deviation will make it very complex to do easy things like resizing it. (Because when starting at `0,0` there are no exceptions - your top left corner never moves)

Comment: tell it to the developer of gridster.js :(

Comment: I guess there must be reasons, but to me that sounds like an ill-conceived idea. Ah well, does it work?

Comment: Yeah I had that as my first result, but because of my knowledge of `0,0` based systems that seemed wrong. My first reply, however, should output the correct amount, first reduce by one (so you calculations happen on the regular `0,0` grid) then add 1 at the end. Have a look at my edited snippet at the bottom.

Comment: We are in a loop... now width and height are again `x*2-1` instead of `x*2` :(

Comment: @FezVrasta Okay, yes, I see. Check once more, I have added a switch statement that will allow you to check for these values... This is very custom and really breaks the nice simplicity but it is consistent, as long as you always use the same keys.

Comment: Thanks!! You saved my day!